# facebook status update

Tags: android, facebook

I am having problem in updating status on facebook. I am using Facebook sdk, the problem is that my status is getting post but not showing text. Here is my code ---->

public class NetRockersUpdate extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         nra = (NetRockersApp)getApplication();
        String result = "Status Posted Successfully";
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("test", msg[0]);
        parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
        try {
             nra.facebook.request(parameters);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check all the below post : I explained how to Post on User wall:

[Post on User's Facebook Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280720/facebook-post-on-friends-wall-in-android/7744153#7744153)

[Post to user Wall with Description,title,caption and link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712281/facebook-post-to-wall-on-android-message-only/7712424#7712424)

[Post on Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649620/facebook-post-to-wall-give-exception/7649781#7649781)..

Comment: @Rocker Are you clarified with Twitter Call back??

Comment: one more thing when I am trying your code with AsyncTask the same issue arises again that status get posted but no text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a "message" key in your parameter.